# Density of events

Tags: probability, statistics

If there is a binomial distribution for some event to occur, I know how to get an average number of events, but I have no idea how to get density of events. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution is a *discrete* distribution, and therefore does not have a density, per se. It has a probability mass function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution